# How does boot animation affect booting time. And how can I decrease the booting time?

Tags: boot-animation, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

What if I load a lite boot animation in my device.
Does is decrease the booting time?

And how to decrease booting time as well as improve my phone's features.

device: Samsung Galaxy y duos GT-s6102
OS: custom ROM XDV3 by XDA Developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BootAnimation doesn't affect boot time. It's just a series of pictures shown in sequence to you, while your phone is ready to give you the GUI.

There is no one certain recipe to make your phone boot twice as fast. Check [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2079550) and [this](http://embien.com/blog/android-boot-time-optimization-techniques/) for possible solutions, to make your phone boot up faster

Comment: "For a faster boot it is better to avoid or use a shorter boot animation. The bootanimation.zip can be tactically placed on the best file system for optimum performance."  Is it?   And what do you think about editing the file  'system -> build.prop' as described at  [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2079550)

Comment: Yeah this build.prop edit might help you out. Use an app from the store to edint the build prop, as hopefully they won't change the permissions of the file. I use Kernel Adituor (ROOT)

Comment: I have rooted my device and currently using custom room, did it with ES-File Explorer